# Sort a 2d array by two separate columns

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Right now I've got a method that can get data from a 2D array, throw it into a Arraylist and then lets me retrieve only the particular parts from that Arraylist that I want.

The code below loops through the `races` Arraylist and places the racers, the total times and how many events they take part in into an array, as of yet unordered in any way.

```
if (!Found && selected.equals(race.GetCat()))
{
    ranking[j][0] = race.GetComp();
    ranking[j][1] = race.GetCat();
    ranking[j][2] = (GetSecs(race.GetRace1())) 
            + (GetSecs(race.GetRace2())) 
            + (GetSecs(race.GetRace3())) + "";

    n++; 
};
Found= false;

for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++)
{
    for (Race race: races)
    {
        if (race.GetComp().equals(array[i][0]) && option.equals(array[i][1]))
        {
            seconds += (GetSes(race.GetRace1()))
                    + (GetSes(race.GetRace2()))
                    + (GetSes(race.GetRace3()));
            total= GetMin(seconds);
            counter++;
        }
        ranking[i][2] = total2 + "";
        ranking[i][3] = counter + "";
    }
}
```

So ranking prints out like

```
RACER      TOTAL TIME     EVENTS TAKING PART IN
name          230.44          2
name          142.51          4
name          523.01          7
name          444.55          2
name          432.18          4
```

And ordering the rankings (String) array so that it is sorted via perhaps the number of events or the total time of the races would not be too difficult.

However, more than one racer will take part in the same number of events, so I was wondering what process or code I would have to go through in order to order the array based on the number of events, and then check to see which rankings share the number of events, and then switch them around based on which total time is lowest

So rankings sorted like

```
george   500    5
john     400    5
george   500    4
david    300    3
carl     200    3
```

is sorted like

```
john     400    5
george   500    5
george   500    4
carl     200    3
david    300    3
```

If something like that is possible. I can put them into an array, and even sort them by one particular column, but sorting them by one, and then by another if the first column has numbers are are the same is totally beyond me, if any of this post makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

1. [Column Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/). It allows you to sort on any column in an ArrayList.
2. [Group Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/). It allows you to sort on multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around it but as a total newbie to Java it's in some ways going in one ear and coming out the other, especially with the group comparator using an arraylist but me needing it for a 2d array

do you perhaps know of an example where it's used, I followed the link and tried to find common points of reference and such but no luck as of now.

Comment: The link gives a simple example of how to create a custom Comparator that sorts on the first column of an array. The example adds each array to an ArrayList but there is no reason you can't add each array to a 2D Array. Once you create you 2D Array you would use `Arrays.sort(...)` instead of Collections.sort(...). Same thing with the GroupComparator, you would use `Arrays.sort(...)`.